# Nested for loop error or indexing error in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, loops, random, hidden-markov-models

I have created this code from scratch.  I want to make a plot and/or histogram of my "Observed" and "State" (these are 2 matrices).  Some problem occurs at the 200th iteration, where my State matrix just becomes all 0's, there is no data being input into the State matrix.  Can anyone troubleshoot the code?  My possible states are {1,2,3}.

UPDATE:
When I adjust my n value, it adjusts how much of length T it will fill.  So, n=5, only runs for 1/5 of T and n=1, run for entire length of T.  I need an nxT matrix at the end (5X1000).  The problem lies in the way I setup my for loops.
I still cannot solve the error though.

```
%Initialize A,pi,T

N = 3; # of states
%A is transition prob matrix
A = [.99,.005,.005;.005,.990,.005;.005,.005,.990];
%pi is initial state vector
pi = [1/3,1/3,1/3];
%T is # of observations per simulation
T = 1000;
%n is # of simulations
n = 5;
%Allocate space for the state matrix
State = zeros(n,T);
Observe = zeros(n,T);
%Create dummy emission matrix, must be row stochastic 
B = ones(n,T)./T;
%loop over # of simulations
for i=1:1:n
    x = rand(1);
    if x <= (1/3)
        State(i,1) = 1;
    elseif x > (1/3) && x <= (2/3)
        State(i,1) = 2;
    else
        State(i,1) = 3;
    end
    if State(i,1) == 1
        b = -1;
    elseif State(i,1) == 2
        b = 0;
    else
        b = 1;
    end
    Observe(i,1)= normrnd(b,1);
    for k=2:1:T
        %Possible state 1,2,3
        State(k) = randsample(N, 1, true, A(State(k-1),:));
        if State == 1
            c = -1;
        elseif State == 2
            c = 0;
        else
            c = 1;
        end
        Observe(i,k)= normrnd(c,1);
    end
end
```

Comment: I just ran again with T = 200, it stopped inputting data at column 40.  So, this program works for only the first 1/5 of the length of the State Matrix.  I can't seem to figure out why.

Comment: `if State == 1` does not do what you want it to do, most likely. And `State(k)` is likely also wrong, likely should be `State(i,k)`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo  I thought it should be State(i,k), but I get this error:

Comment: Index in position 1 is invalid. Array indices must be positive integers or logical values.
Error in hm (line 36)
        State(i,k) = randsample(3, 1, true, A(State(k-1),:));

Comment: I found it!  randsample(3, 1, true, A(State(k-1),:)); --> State(k-1) is missing the i index

Comment: Indeed, and also `State == 1` is a large matrix, not a Boolean. You are missing indices there as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
State(k) = randsample(N, 1, true, A(State(k-1),:));
```

This line is missing index (i) in position 1 inside State(k-1).  It should be:

```
State(i,k) = randsample(N, 1, true, A(State(i,k-1),:));
```